# Weird result with empty vector and paste0 in R

Tags: r

I'm writing a function which generates vector of filenames based on content of data frame.
It works perfectly for a non-empty data frame, but produces weird result for an empty data frame:

```
> head(c)
  id nobs
1  1  117
2  2 1041
3  3  243
4  4  474
5  5  402
6  6  228
> cc <- c[c$nobs > 1000, ]
> cc
     id nobs
2     2 1041
154 154 1095
248 248 1005
> paste0("specdata", "/", sprintf("%03d", cc$id), ".csv")
[1] "specdata/002.csv" "specdata/154.csv" "specdata/248.csv"
> cc <- c[c$nobs > 5000, ]
> paste0("specdata", "/", sprintf("%03d", cc$id), ".csv")
[1] "specdata/.csv"
```

Does anybody have an idea why it produces "specdata/.csv" instead of an empty vector?
(At the moment I use if(nrow(cc)) to return an empty vector, but I hope there must be a better way to do it)

Answer (score 1):

paste0 is used for concatenating strings.

```
paste0("specdata", "/", sprintf("%03d", cc$id), ".csv")
```

In your case, `sprintf("%03d", cc$id)` will return empty string because `cc` is empty.
Here, you are concatenating `"spedata", "/", "", ".csv"` 
and the result you get is expected.

Comment: This could be also done without the `paste0` call.  `sprintf('specdata/%03d.csv', cc$id)`